# The statement "people are humans", as a metaphor?

Tags: meaning-in-context, metaphors

I want to use the phrase "people are humans", as to differentiate between the perception of mindless ants running around, and individuals with complex feelings and understandings of the world.

So for instance:

> That the country is full of uneducated masses is, to me, fundamentally untrue; people are humans and their creativity defines them.

Thoughts?

Comment: It's a little too casual if you're writing an academic paper.

Comment: It's for an undergraduate admissions essay, to be honest. One of my concerns is that it won't be obvious that "people are humans" is a metaphor, rather than an apparent fact.

Comment: Hi Jaico,  while this is an interesting question it is not really an English-Language question as delineated in the [help]; it's more of a writing advice request.

Comment: (Personally I think you should change it; if you want to contrast them to mindless ants, do so explicitly.)

Comment: I see Hellion, I'm sorry, I have a hard time navigating stack exchange and finding appropriate forums. If a moderator wants me to take down the question, I will do it. Thanks for your suggestion though, I may just do that.

Comment: The problem with the sentence, if it is a problem, is almost too subtle to attract notice. [1] The word "people" is freighted with a primary meaning which does not help you, for it is a singular which means "nation" or "tribe." The phrase "people are" is always faintly troubled. [2] "Persons are human" doesn't do what you want. [3] What you really mean to say is "humans are human" -- or, if you would flout PC, "men are men" -- but this probably achieves the wrong effect. I am not sure that the sentence can be much improved as it stands. Either leave it, or write something else.

Comment: Even if the country were full of uneducated masses (and most countries were fairly recently, say 200 years ago) people are still individuals and have potential.  I haven't said this as well as I would if I were writing an admissions essay, but play around with this, if it is what you mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"People are humans" just doesn't work. This might:

> "That the country is full of uneducated masses is, to me, fundamentally untrue; every person is an individual who is defined by his or her creativity."

Comment: Hubbard's sentence is good. However, in your paper, even Hubbard's sentence will fall flat on its face unless you follow it with some kind of substantiation. Without even an anecdote to back it up, it is just a flat assertion, which will put off a discerning reader. (Of course, there exist many undiscerning readers who actually like unsubstantiated assertions, so long as these assertions confirm their prior biases. Your mileage may vary.)

Answer (score 1):

Although the two words are often used synonymously, when used in contrast, there is a subtle semantic difference between the two words. According to the American Dictionary of the English Language by Noah Webster, a human is a member of the species:

> [HU'MAN](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/human), adjective [Latin humanus; Heb. form, species.]
>
> 1. Belonging to man or mankind; pertaining or relating to the race of man; as a human voice; human shape; human nature; human knowledge; human life.
> 2. Having the qualities of a man.
> 3. Profane; not sacred or divine; as a human author. [Not in use.]

(Actually, keep that profane and allegedly unused meaning in mind.)

Person refers to the totality of our being:

> [PERSON](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/Person), noun per'sn. [Latin persona; said to be compounded of per, through or by, and sonus, sound; a Latin word signifying primarily a mask used by actors on the state.]
>
> 1. An individual human being consisting of body and soul. We apply the word to living beings only, possessed of a rational nature; the body when dead is not called a person It is applied alike to a man, woman or child.
>
> A person is a thinking intelligent being. [[— John Locke](http://www.oswego.edu/%7Edelancey/471_DIR/471_LECTURES/PI.html)]

Thus you can be human and not a person. It may even be possible for a person to be something that is not human, provided it has both body and soul, although that is a discussion best saved for philosophers at another time.

A.D.E.L's. definition of [Soul](http://webstersdictionary1828.com/Dictionary/soul) is also of relevance, although it is a bit too long to include everything here. Summarized it is in part our intellectual understanding, our vitality, our affection, our generosity our spirit and our power. Perhaps most relevantly it is somewhat synonymous with the mind itself:

> 1. The spiritual, rational and immortal substance in man, which distinguishes him from brutes; that part of man which enables him to think and reason, and which renders him a subject of moral government. The immortality of the soul is a fundamental article of the christian system. Such is the nature of the human soul that it must have a God, an object of supreme affection.

We do have have a humble phrase "only human" which highlights that the specified entities, unlike an omniscient, omnipotent and benevolent deity or some robot with awesome computational power if you'd rather, we are inherently imperfect beings, prone to  various vices and deficiencies. Macmillan defines "[someone is only human](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/someone-is-only-human)" as:

> used for saying someone has been weak in the ways that most people are weak and should not be blamed for their behavior

That is mostly accurate when used in the singular form I suppose. It is also sometimes it is also said that "People are only human" to describe the deficiencies  you can expect most or all of us share in commonality, [Isaiah 2:22](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Isaiah%202%3A22) in [The New Century Version Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%202:21-22&version=NCV), [International Children's Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%202:21-22&version=ICB), and [Expanded Bible](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Isaiah%202:21-22&version=EXB) all make use of the phrase in this way, though the quote. However, I think [this following quotation](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/6854481-people-are-only-human-they-let-there-emotions-get-the) demonstrates the phrase better, allegedly by Darnell Houston (whomever that is) whether Brainy Quotes properly attributed it or not (I don't trust isolated quotations much, but it's the sentiment, rather than the person saying it I care about here):

> People are only human. They let there emotions get the best of them sometimes.
>
> It's a weakness. Some can't handle rejection without reaction, so when you say "No" it burns some people who are in high positions. Do expect him to be condescending.

This is all lead-up to the point that statement you are making expresses your sentiment backwards. You should refer to what we certainly know ourselves to be first, then serve a reminder of the element we either forgot or do not know.

**As such**, metaphorically it would be better to say "humans are people" than the other way around to allude to the presence of a mind within that hunk of flesh.